# How to Update Value of One table using Another Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two snowflake tables called as TABLE1 and TABLE2. I would like to update the rows of Table1 by Table2 only if some field values match with table2.

Table1

```
Date       columnA  columnB  sum     reff
2021-09-27   1        Y      10       A
2021-09-27   2        Y      20       B
2021-09-27   3        Y      30       C
2021-09-27   4        Y      40       D
2021-09-27   5        S      8000     D
```

Table2

```
Date        columnA columnB  sum    reff
2021-09-27     5      Y      10       A
2021-09-27     2      Y      100      B
2021-09-27     3      Y      100      C
2021-09-27     4      Y      100      D
2021-09-27     6      S      8000     D
```

I want to Update rows if fields `Date, columnA, columnB, reff` are Matching in both tables (Update of rows should be in Table1)

Excepted output

```
Date        columnA columnB  sum    reff
2021-09-27     1      Y      10       A
2021-09-27     2      Y      100      B
2021-09-27     3      Y      100      C
2021-09-27     4      Y      100      D
2021-09-27     5      S      8000     D
2021-09-27     5      Y      10       A
2021-09-27     6      S      8000     D
```

can someone help me please. Using `select` query to get the `Excepted output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is a full outer join.
this will join rows on your matching condition, but it will keep rows that don't have any matches (rows that don't need to get updated in table 1 AND rows that are new in table2).

when the join is not successful, you want to use whichever is not null.
when the join is successful, you want to use the values from table 2

This should do the trick I think:

```sql
select
    IFNULL(t2.Date, t1.Date) as Date,
    IFNULL(t2.columnA, t1.columnA) as columnA,
    IFNULL(t2.columnB, t1.columnB) as columnB,
    IFNULL(t2.sum, t1.sum) as sum,
    IFNULL(t2.reff, t1.reff) as reff
from
    Table2 t2
full outer join
    Table1 t1
    on t2.Date = t1.Date and t2.columnA = t1.columnA and t2.columnB = t1.columnB and t2.reff = t1.reff
```

Another option to update table1 in place would be to use a merge statement. Updating on a match and inserting a record when not matched.

Comment: Thanks david! btw ISNULL didn't work for me, I changed ISNULL to COALESCE and it worked..

Comment: If there are some NULL in columnA in both table, can those rows also be updated? . Currently I see those remains unchanged. Is it possible to update those also!!!

Comment: my mistake, in Snowflake it's `IFNULL` instead of `ISNULL`. `COALESCE` works just as well.

Comment: you can use `EQUAL_NULL( t2.Date, t1.Date )` etc. in the join condition, which will return true if they are both null. insteaed of the standard `=`

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake merge also will work to get expected output:

```js
    merge into source1 a
using source2 b
on 
 a.date = b.date and
 a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA and 
 a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB and 
 a.reff = b.reff
when matched then
    update set
        a.date = b.date,
        a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA,
        a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB,
        a.sum = b.sum,
        a.reff = b.reff
when not matched then insert
    (a.date, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB, a.sum, a.reff) values (b.date, b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB, b.sum, b.reff);
```

[image]